# Regex-tagged questions: Can they require an additional tag?

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible, when users tag a question with regex, that they be encouraged/required to specify another tag, much like what happens when a question is tagged [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql). Of course PCRE varies a bit from language to language, but more importantly, languages vary greatly in the functions that invoke the regex engine.

Further, many engines do not support lookbehinds so sometimes an easy task with one flavor of regex becomes cumbersome with another flavor ("I want to find question marks in this string that are not preceded by backslashes.")

I was surprised that I couldn't find this question already, but neither a few minutes of google-searching, or the Similar Questions box, had anything relevant.

Comment: What *language*? Plz give me the regex asap. [Fresh example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736180/using-regex-to-match-everything-before-the-word-containing-a-comma)

Comment: @chryor thanks. can't believe it was also asked yesterday lol